# Android ListView image flickers while trying to load the image from SQLite Database

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-listview

I implemented `ListView` to display some items from the `SQLite Database`. Each of which contains an `Image` and some `Data`.

I want my `ListView` to work faster even if it contains thousand rows of data. So i tried to implement some optimizations that i have noticed. Here is the basic `structure` of my `CustomCursorAdapter`:

```
Class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    Cursor cursor;
    public CustomCursorAdapter(..., Cursor _cursor)
    {
        cursor = _cursor;
    }

    public void bindView(View _view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor)
    {
        if( view.getTage() == null)
        {
            //create and initialize a new holder and set it to view tag.
            holder = new Holder();
            ...
            ...
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(defaultDrawable);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        String mediaID = _cursor.getString("media_id");

        //create an asyncTask to load the image from database
        new MediaLoader(context, holder.imageView).execute(mediaID);
    }

    private class MediaLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Media>
    {
        private Context context;
        private final WeakReference <ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public MediaLoader(Context _context, ImageView _imageView)
        {
            context = _context;
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(_imageView);
        }

        protected Media doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            String _mediaID = args[0];  
            return MediaDataManager.getInstance(_context).getMediaObjectForListAdapter(_mediaID);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Media _media)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(_media);

            if( imageViewReference != null )
            {
                ImageView _imageView = imageViewReference.get();

                if(_imageView != null)
                {
                    if( _media != null && _media.getImage() != null )
                    {
                        _imageView.setImageBitmap(_media.getImage());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _imageView.setImageDrawable(defaultDrawable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//Media Loader ends.
}//Custom Cursor Adapter Ends.
```

Using this approach loading time of image seemed ok to me.

But in some android devices (low configuration ones), i am experiencing `image flickering`. For some reason during `scrolling` or even `loading` i noticed images keeps changing throughout the list. But the final image that remains in every row is always the `correct` one.

**Edit:**
Loading of images one by one is not a problem for me. But showing some irrelevant images before showing the correct one is my only concern.

I couldn't find any helpful resource by searching. Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that you have 100 rows in your `Cursor`. And, let's suppose that this is a really short `ListView`, where only 2 rows are visible. And, let's suppose that after you load up the adapter in the `ListView`, the user flings through the whole list.

What your code will do is:

- Fork **100** `AsyncTask` instances, where on Android 3.2+ they will only execute one at a time (unless your `targetSdkVersion` is fairly low)
- Download **100** images
- Put each of those **100** images into the rows as they come in

All of this, for a case where you only need 2 images, the ones at the end.

This is why you really should consider using an existing library for this sort of thing, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), where you could plug in logic to pull values out of... well, wherever your images are actually stored. These sorts of libraries already handle these sorts of situations.

If you insist upon implementing this yourself, you will need to add in the smarts to realize that if the user scrolled the list and we are recycling a row, that we no longer need previous tasks that are tied to that row. Cancel those and queue up a task to download what you need. Also, consider using `executeOnExecutor()` on API Level 11+, so some of these will run in parallel.

Comment: I have Edited my description. Hope my intentions are more clear now.

Comment: @user3226143: This is covered in my answer. If you don't want irrelevant images, cancel the relevant `AsyncTask` as soon as you know the image that it is trying to download is irrelevant.

Comment: I am sorry i went through your reply bit quickly earlier. It will be more helpful for me if you can help me out with some detailed ideas or some documents where i can read more about `recycling` image and `canceling` unnecessary database query. Once i tried using some position reference to keep track of useful indexes, but trying to fix it only caused more issues.